# Is there a more elegant way to use Color Literals in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

**Edit**: It isn't recommended to use `Color Literal` in SwiftUI. Rather, it's proper to use color assets. However, this question comes out of curiosity.

Swift's `Color Literal` provides a visual way to get colors within your code.

With SwiftUI, a `Color` instance can be defined from a `Color Literal` using the `Color(_ color: UIColor)` initializer, like so:

[image: Image 1]

However, attempting to create a `Color` instance without this initializer gives an error:

[image]

```
Error: Cannot convert value of type 'UIColor' to specified type 'Color'
```

Is there any workaround where I can create a `Color` instance from just a `Color Literal` without having to use the `Color(_ color: UIColor)` initializer?

Here is the closest I could get to a solution, using an extension of `UIColor`:

```swift
extension UIColor {
  
  /// Gets a `Color` instance
  var c: Color {
    Color(self)
  }
}
```

[image]

Please note that this question is merely for code elegance, and that the trivial solution would be to use the initializer.

Comment: There is no `Color` literals yet and actually I don't see what's bad with `static let royalBlue = Color(#blue_literal_here)`

Comment: Color literal is something that should not be used outside playgrounds. Please, use color assets instead.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks for the advice. Again, this question is really trivial and more out of curiosity. I have edited my question to include this information, per your comment. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YOu can use `_ExpressibleByColorLiteral` to accept UIColor literal for Color

```
extension Color: _ExpressibleByColorLiteral {
    public init(_colorLiteralRed red: Float, green: Float, blue: Float, alpha: Float) {
       self = Color(red: Double(red), green: Double(green), blue: Double(blue), opacity: Double(alpha))
    }
}
```

Usage

```
private let whiteColor: Color = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
private let blueColor: Color = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1215686277, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.4235294163, alpha: 1)
```

[image]